# Why can't comments be downvoted?

Tags: feature-request, comments, down-votes

Since comment upvotes don't yield any reputation, I'm just wondering why comments can be upvoted but not downvoted.  I see a lot of comments with flat out wrong information or unhelpful responses, and downvoting could add weight to whether those responses are visible by default, or go under the "view x more comments" expander.

I'm sure there's a rationale, just wondering what it is and why more people don't request this feature.

EDIT:  I know there's a flag feature, but I'm more inclined to use that for offensive or off-topic comments.  Am I wrong on that?

Comment: See: [Should downvoting be allowed on comments?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3615/should-downvoting-be-allowed-on-comments)

Comment: ah, interesting -- not sure why my searches didn't turn that up.

Comment: @trpt4him That one is on Meta Stackoverflow, which also serves as a meta for the whole SE network. It won't come up on a search of Meta Superuser.

Answer (score 1):

There's actually some value in keeping wrong *answers* around, as long as they're *visibly wrong*.

But comments are already a bit of a distraction - keeping worthless or outright *harmful* ones tacked onto a post is a luxury.

So you have a few options:

1. reply, noting the error (so the author can delete it or correct it).
2. flag it, noting the error (so a moderator can delete it, or the system itself if enough folks flag)
3. both 1 and 2

Note that up-votes counter flags to a certain degree (at least when it comes to automatic deletion). See also: [How does comment voting and flagging work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17364/how-do-comment-voting-and-flagging-work)