# Remove upvoting on comments under a question, only allow downvoting

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, comments, up-votes

If you don't know an answer, why don't you simply pass-by?

No question is stupid. We are all human beings and can have different ideas at times and just because of difference, another idea can't be wrong.

If you don't like someone else's idea, just skip it, don't make it dirty using obnoxious comments just to get some up-votes.

Your votes here are not dollars, you can't expend them anywhere. It is just a measure of how you contribute to community. Make this contribution worthy of its figure. If you can't answer some questions let others do it.

My suggestion is to remove up-votes for comments (just) under the questions, only down-votes there.

Comment: The purpose of StackExchange isn't to serve your opinions, so while your opinion may be that no question is bad, the opinion of StackExchange is that *many* questions are bad. I'm not familiar with your specific interactions in any way, but you have to realize what you think of SE or how you feel about SE has nothing at all to do with what SE exists for. It's purpose is it's own, which is explicitly to gather high quality questions with authoritative answers to share with the internet at large - *not for participants of the site*.

Comment: I had the similar opinion that if you can't get answer anywhere you can get it at stack-exchange... [My question](http://superuser.com/questions/690797/orbit-downloader-older-versions-safe-or-not)

Comment: You people marked is as "opinion-based" Now tell me how would you tell whether a software contains malacious code or not... on the basis of opinions, did ESET found Win32,Orbiter.A merely based on there opinion? All I had to ask was do you have any report that Orbit Downloader 4.0.0.2 contains any bad piece or not.

Comment: You don't earn reputation from comment upvotes, anyway, so it does not really matter...

Comment: Have you looked at the [help center](http://superuser.com/help)?

Comment: You can't downvote comments, either. Only questions and answers...

Comment: I never read any help section. I don't have that much of time I have enough books to read.

Comment: Sometimes. Changing the title changes entire context.

Comment: *"I never read any help section. I don't have that much of time [...]"* A lot more respect for your own time than for that of everybody else. Noted.

Comment: @swapna while ideas can not be stupid , why down vote it ?

Comment: @swapna"I never read any help section. I don't have that much of time [...]" Reading the help section would have taken less time than to post this concern you have.

Comment: @dmckee I didn't mean that, I just said that I don't have time to read help manuals, No offence to those who wrote them, it's just my dis-interest.

Comment: @CarlB I don't have any concern, actually I was looking for some time-pass.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why can't comments be downvoted?](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/7147/why-cant-comments-be-downvoted)

Comment: Good observation! +1

Answer (score 12):

> If you don't know an answer, why don't you simply pass-by?

Your meta-question (quoted above) is based upon the assumption that the question you asked on the main site meets our criteria for what a valid question is.

**IF** you asked a question that is:

- On-topic,
- Answerable (with something other than opinions),
- Focused on an actual problem you're having,

...then I believe that people would indeed "pass-by" and not say anything. In fact, if it's a good question, they would probably *upvote* the question to indicate "good job asking this question, I hope someone else knows".

On SuperUser alone, there are *thousands* of examples of this type of behavior, where people who do not know the answer to a good question do not leave any comments, but they upvote the question.

Since you didn't have "time" to read the help center, here are two facts about SuperUser that you absolutely must know:

1. **SuperUser is not a forum.**
2. **The purpose of SuperUser is not to answer *your* question or solve *your* problem. Rather, the purpose of SuperUser is to compile knowledge.**

Questions whose answers are not adding to the body of knowledge that SuperUser has, are going to be put on hold, and eventually closed, and eventually deleted. That's our way of *Quality Control*, which sorts the "noise" down to the bottom, and eventually nukes it into oblivion, so that whatever remains is reliable, quality knowledge.

It is the *duty* of SuperUser moderators (both elected moderators and high-rep users with moderator privileges) to ensure that questions which do not meet our standards are marked as such, by being closed, downvoted if warranted, and eventually deleted.

We have explained to you multiple times why the question you asked is not acceptable. If we always just "pass-by" questions that do not meet our standards, the site would be *flooded* with awful stuff, and nobody would ever be able to find the actually useful answers.

If you want to be a participant in this community, you will need to learn about and abide by the policies and standards we have set forth. These standards are what sets this site apart from your everyday, run of the mill, anything-goes forum. There are *hundreds* of very low quality forums that accept any and all questions, where you can go to post your question, if you want to post that question on a site without standards. Pick one and post it.

The thing is, you probably won't get an answer; or if you do, it won't be a good one. Why? Because the exact reason that allows you to post your question, is the same reason why the answers on those forums are so bad. In fact, you might not even *get* an answer -- not a single comment -- on your question in such forums. At least here, we are trying to tell you why your question is based on an improper line of thinking, and suggesting how you can improve your analysis of the situation by reasoning more logically and trying to understand things like information theory and system security.

In essence, even though we've closed your question, you have received more help from the SuperUser and Meta SuperUser communities than you're likely to receive on any other forum. And you haven't even asked a good question yet! Just imagine how useful the site would be if you asked a good question.

*Please* read at least a part of the Help Center if you want to really understand the great experiment that is StackExchange. It's not just a place where you can ask smart people anything and have them dump their knowledge on you. You only get out what you put in. Ask good questions, get good answers. Ask bad questions, get... close votes.

Answer (score 9):

Comment upvotes are... special. They don't actually really mean anything (I seem to recall, at most a badge). On the other hand, comments are a useful way to extract and elicit more information from an OP, or to suggest something too minor to be a question on its own. A comment upvote is just a way to say "this comment added something" (and we don't downvote, we *flag* comments).

And yeah, read the help center. Its a little messier than it used to be (god, I miss the old FAQ) but it covers nearly everything you need to know about stackexchange... and looking at this question, you may need it.